# Constraint issues from iPhone 6 to 6 Plus

Tags: ios, user-interface, debugging, swift2, constraints

I am having an issue when I put my constraints on my app's text fields and labels they do not stay in the same spot of the background when moving to 6 plus. For example my background has the word Date: then my label fills in next to it the current date. When I move from 6 to 6 Plus the date isn't staying in the same place on the background. I am using the suggested constraints button, is there any way to set the constraints to stay at a certain spot on background?

Ill attach two screenshots showing you the problem. I am a freshman student in college and I am trying to finish a summer project! Any tips would be awesome!

[6 image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlLYT.png)
[6 plus image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc4j4.png)

Comment: I think the images weren't uploaded correctly. All I am seeing are the paths: /Users/Matthew/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-08-30 at 10.57.42 AM.png

/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Screen Shot 2016-08-30 at 10.58.31 AM.png

Comment: I fixed the image links.

Comment: Could you explain how the constraints are set on this screen? Thanks!